# Facing issue in Webservice Call from IBM WAS7

Tags: java, web-services, websphere, websphere-7

I have a web service deployed on Oracle Weblogic 11G. The web service has been tested using weblogic's internal test client and is working.

The Client stubs for this web service is built using IBM WAS 7 inbuilt script (WSDL2JAVA.SH).
The stub is then used to call the web service and has been deployed on IBM WAS7.

The issue as below is at the call of the web service.

The method call to the stub it self throws this exception.

The wierd part is that acitivity as per the request from the client is recorded in the Logs.

That means the web service is getting the request but the client is unable to analyse the response.

Please help.

[5/24/12 13:02:27:655 GMT+05:30] 00000027 SystemErr R java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.xmlsoap.SOAPElement incompatible with java.lang.String
[5/24/12 13:02:27:655 GMT+05:30] 00000027 SystemErr R at $Proxy21.inquireFinnOneLMS(Unknown Source)
[5/24/12 13:02:27:655 GMT+05:30] 00000027 SystemErr R at com.iflex.fcat.hdfc_ln.LNRoot.sendRequest(LNRoot.java:1296)
[5/24/12 13:02:27:655 GMT+05:30] 00000027 SystemErr R at com.iflex.fcat.hdfc_ln.RSLoanAccountSummaryBean.doProcess(RSLoanAccountSummaryBean.java:175)

Comment: If you got RAD Do "Generate Client" for the wsdl instead of using wsdl2java, works great for me every time

Comment: I dont have RAD...cant use that...i have to work with IBM Specific libraries for Client

Comment: RAD - Rational Application Developer, It is the official development environment for Websphere

Comment: Sorry cant use it..any way with the wsdl2java.sh...???...also this issue has been raised with ibm and it has gone to developer level issue...will update if any update is recieved...still if anyone knows this issue...please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been found to be on the IBM WAS server and has been fixed in the next FixPack.

The WAS libraries were not able to understand the SOAP Element and was throwing and error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run wsdl2java against a provided wsdl file, or against a wsdl URL served by the service itself?

At first glance, it would appear to be a disconnect between the WSDL used when the client was generated and the actual running service.

Comment: As long as the file is current, no, it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I know and its wierd...but the issue exists...i have raised a concern with IBM also...but they are also analysing the same...

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the endptEnabler.sh (or endptEnabler.bat)

-> endptEnabler.sh -v -CCtrace=*=all -CCtracefile=/tmp/trace.log myEAR.ear

check this for details;

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0404_bose/0404_bose.html

Here is a link where an issue related to endptEnabler was reported and resolved
http://fixunix.com/websphere/558857-accessing-jax-ws-endpoint.html

Hope it helps.